# Error when creating multiple columns in one table with same values

Tags: sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

When I try to exeecute the folliwng in SQL, I get error, I am trying to add multiple columns with same value to one table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vendor` (
  `product_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL
), `Vendor_SKU_or_Stock_Number` varchar(255) NOT NULL
), `Brand_Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
), `Image_URL5`varchar(255) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

ERROR: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' `Vendor_SKU_or_Stock_Number` varchar(255) NOT NULL
), `Brand_Name` varchar(255)' at line 13

Please help

Comment: try removing the closing brackets, there are way too many

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too many closing parenthesis, and your table name and field names should not be quoted.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vendor (
  product_id varchar(255) NOT NULL
  , Vendor_SKU_or_Stock_Number varchar(255) NOT NULL
  , Brand_Name varchar(255) NOT NULL
  , Image_URL5 varchar(255) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: I am still getting #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''Vendor_SKU_or_Stock_Number' varchar(255 NOT NULL
, 'Brand_Name' varchar(255 NOT' at line 13

Comment: Remove the tics around your field names.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Great! Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Removed ")"

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vendor` (
      `product_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL
    , `Vendor_SKU_or_Stock_Number` varchar(255) NOT NULL
    , `Brand_Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
    , `Image_URL5`varchar(255) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vendor` (
  `product_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL
, `Vendor_SKU_or_Stock_Number` varchar(255) NOT NULL
, `Brand_Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
, `Image_URL5`varchar(255) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vendor (
  product_id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
vendor_SKU_or_Stock_Number varchar(255) NOT NULL,
brand_Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
image_URL5 varchar(255) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=latin1;
```